# Fill the list based on specific condition

Tags: haskell

I had an interview, and interviewer gave me a problem about list.

For example, the original list would be like `[0,1,0,0,2,0,0,1]`, the `2` should fill the list as far as it can unless it encounters 1. So the output would be `[0,1,2,2,2,2,2,1]`.

One example:

```
[0,2,1,0,1,2,0,0]
```

output:

```
[2,2,1,0,1,2,2,2]
```

Another example:

```
[2,0,0,0,1,1,0,1]
```

output:

```
[2,2,2,2,1,1,0,1]
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [Deterministic Finite Automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) with two states `s_fill` and `s_keep` as follows:

```
fill2 :: [Int] -> [Int]
fill2 xs = s_keep xs []
   where s_keep []     w = reverse w
         s_keep (c:cs) w = if c == 2 then s_fill cs (c:w) else s_keep cs (c:w)
         s_fill []     w = reverse w
         s_fill (c:cs) w = if c == 1 then s_keep cs (c:w)
                          else s_fill cs (2:w)
```

In the state `s_fill`, the function `fill2` keeps filling `2` onto the head of an accumulator, until `1` is met, in which case the DFA jumps to state `s_keep`.

In `s_keep`, `fill2` pushes each element itself back to the accumulator `w` until `2` is encountered, in which case the DFA jumps to `s_fill`.

The recursion terminates when the remainder list (the first parameter of s_{keep,fill}) is empty. In this case, the function return the reverse of the accumulator as elements near head were pushed deeper near the tail of the accumulator.

So far, the function `fill2` fills 2 from left to right. The rest of the job is to fill from right to left on the result of `(fill2 xs)`, which can be easily obtained on the reverse of `(fill2 xs)` as follows:

```
fill2' xs = reverse $ fill2 $reverse $fill2 xs
```

Output:

```
*Main> fill2' [0,1,0,0,2,0,0,1]
[0,1,2,2,2,2,2,1]
*Main> fill2' [0,2,1,0,1,2,0,0]
[2,2,1,0,1,2,2,2]
*Main> fill2' [2,0,0,0,1,1,0,1]
[2,2,2,2,1,1,0,1]
```

and

```
*Main> fill2' [0,0,1,0,2,0,1]
[0,0,1,2,2,2,1]
```

--- Original Version of Code ---

(Thanks to @ØrjanJohansen for pointing out the issue of the original version of the code below with the initial state and direction of fill).

```
fill2 :: [Int] -> [Int]
fill2 str = s_fill str []
   where s_keep []     w = reverse w
         s_keep (c:cs) w = if c == 2 then s_fill cs (c:w) else s_keep cs (c:w)
         s_fill []     w = reverse w
         s_fill (c:cs) w = if c == 1 then s_keep cs (c:w)
                          else s_fill cs (2:w)
```

Comment: I don't think this does what is intended in other cases. Consider `fill2 [0,0,1,0,2,0,1] == [2,2,1,0,2,2,1]`, I believe the intended result is `[0,0,1,2,2,2,1]`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Could you explain your logic? Actually, I am not sure what the intended output is. I was following the description `the 2 should fill the list as far as it can unless it encounters 1`, and I assumed that the "filling" will start again when `2` is encountered based on `One example:

[0,2,1,0,1,2,0,0]

output:

[2,2,1,0,1,2,2,2]`

Comment: My logic is that the first two `0`s shouldn't be filled since there's a `1` between them and the nearest `2`, while the third one *should* be filled since it's next to a `2`. The examples clearly show that `2`s must fill both left- and rightward.

Comment: More directly, your code doesn't work for the very *first* example in the original question, `[0,1,0,0,2,0,0,1]`.

Answer (score 3):

If we can get a function `fillRight` that fills to the right, i.e.

```
fillRight [0,2,1,0,1,2,0,0] = [0,2,1,0,1,2,2,2]
```

then we can easily achieve the full solution:

```
fillLeft = reverse . fillRight . reverse
fill = fillLeft . fillRight
```

so we can spend our energy on `fillRight`.  As others have pointed out, this is a simple state machine, which I would write in the following way which elucidates the state transitions (note how I added a parameter to keep track of the state):

```
fillRight' :: Bool -> [Int] -> [Int]
fillRight' _     []     = []
fillRight' True  (0:xs) = 2 : fillRight' True  xs
fillRight' False (0:xs) = 0 : fillRight' False xs
fillRight' _     (1:xs) = 1 : fillRight' False xs
fillRight' _     (2:xs) = 2 : fillRight' True  xs
```

then close it off by setting an initial state

```
fillRight = fillRight' False
```

Answer (score 3):

It is easier to solve this problem if you think of `1` as whitespace, and `0` and `2` as letters in words

```
import Data.List

words'::[Int]->[[Int]]
words' [] = [[]]
words' x =
  case rest of
    (1:after) -> first:words' after
    _ -> [first]
    where (first, rest) = break (== 1) x

fill::[Int]->[Int]
fill x = intercalate [1] $
     map (\x -> replicate (length x) (if 2 `elem` x then 2 else 0)) $
     words' x
```

First split the incoming data into "words", then simply map words to all `2`s if a single 2 is inside of a word.

This will work O(n) in the input size, and can even handle an infinite input stream.

---

examples

```
main = do
  print $ fill [1,0,0,0]
  print $ fill [1,0,0]
  print $ fill [0,0,1,0,2,0,1]
  print $ fill [0,1,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,1,2,0,1]
  print $ fill [0,1,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0,1]
  print $ fill [0,2,1,0,1,2,0,0]
  print $ fill [2,0,0,0,1,1,0,1]
  print $ fill [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1]
```

output

```
[1,0,0,0]
[1,0,0]
[0,0,1,2,2,2,1]
[0,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,1,2,2,1]
[0,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,1,2,2,1]
[2,2,1,0,1,2,2,2]
[2,2,2,2,1,1,0,1]
[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1]
```

Comment: It can't handle `repeat 0`, but then I think nothing can.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen- yeah, it is an inherent limitation....  even a human working by hand would be in limbo about whether to jot down 0s or 2s until it sees the first 1 or 2.  It is one of those pathological cases that would probably be obvious in practice though (kind of like saying a calculator can't give you an answer to a question until the whole number is entered....  and the number is an infinite string of 9s).

Answer (score 1):

Here is code-golf solution:

```
fill xs = foldr step replicate xs 0 0 where
    step 0 r l m = r (l + 1) m
    step 1 r l m = replicate l m ++ 1 : r 0 0
    step 2 r l m = r (l + 1) 2

main = do
  print $ fill [1,0,0,0]
  print $ fill [1,0,0]
  print $ fill [0,0,1,0,2,0,1]
  print $ fill [0,1,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,1,2,0,1]
  print $ fill [0,1,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0,1]
  print $ fill [0,2,1,0,1,2,0,0]
  print $ fill [2,0,0,0,1,1,0,1]
  print $ fill [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1]
```

Results in

```
[1,0,0,0]
[1,0,0]
[0,0,1,2,2,2,1]
[0,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,1,2,2,1]
[0,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,1,2,2,1]
[2,2,1,0,1,2,2,2]
[2,2,2,2,1,1,0,1]
[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1]
```

Comment: Nifty. But surely you mean ``f a=foldr s r a 0 0;s 1c l=(++1:c 0 0).r l;s t c l=c(l+1).max t;r=replicate``

Comment: @Ørjan Johansen, Very nice, especially the using of `max`.